# C# - Tray Notification Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Could someone point me in the right direction, for Tray Notification Windows, similar to the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple interface to the notification tray called NotifyIcon in WinForms.

Once you can grab its events (Clicked, DoubleClicked, etc.) you can pick whether you want to show a context-menu or a form.

As noted by schlingel, in the example you provided is a custom form without a window border, drawn right next to the notification tray.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Winforms? If so use a standard form without border ([FormBorderStyle None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hw8kes41%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) and draw it yourself.