# VB.net or C# : Want to write in the notification area [Windows]

Tags: c#, .net, windows, notifications

I have a simple question
How could I write some text with .NET in the notification area in Windows 10/11 ?

Something similar like that : (the ENG, I want exactly the same thing with the text I want)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1EW1.png)

I precise I have all the rights so there is not problem to give admin permissions.
If you have an idea, feel free to participate and help me
Thanks
Respectfully

Comment: It's an icon, not a text. But you can create any icon (with short text) and place it into tray. See [`NotifyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon) class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Tray Notification Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483779/c-sharp-tray-notification-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to freely type in there, you will have to draw your text and the convert them to icons then use a NotifyIcon and set the icon to your icon:

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("blank.bmp");
 using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
 {
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    g.DrawString("text", new Font("Arial", 8), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
 }
 myBitmap.Save("text.ico", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
 notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("text.ico");
```

Untested who knows if it would work, and delete the old icons when changing text.